# The confined, plated with gold

Tags: riddle

> I am confined. I have been for all my life. All my life I have lived in this sphere I call home, although I have golden plates all over me. Sure, my warden ensures I have my needs fulfilled, but I am not going anywhere.  Within my sphere, the only place I can really go to is my castle, although it of course of a small size. I explore it from time to time, but other than that, there isn't much I can do.

Who or what am I?

Comment: This is *way* too easy compared to your previous riddles :)

Comment: I try to do with different difficulty levels. However, I didn't expect the one about war to take so long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> a goldfish.
>
>  The sphere is an aquarium.
>  Golden plates indicate goldfish.
>  The warden aka as the owner feed the fish and cleans the water.
>  A castle is often a decoration in there.